# Send email from case in partner portal

Tags: administration, partner-portal

Currently in my configuration of `partner portal` the partner can see and update cases via their partner portal. They can read emails that are attached to the case (as a related list), however they cannot reply to or forward these emails. Is it possible to enable reply, reply all, forward options for emails in cases in the partner portal? Are there licensing constraints?